# How can you block / disable the accepted ways of encoding in your browser?

Tags: google-chrome, encoding, gzip, opera

I went to: https://www.esolutions.se/whatsmyinfo and realized there is tons of info shown about you. I have managed to change most of the info (such as User-Agent, Screen size, and I have disabled all .dll plugins too). But now there is also this:

```
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, lzma, sdch
```

My question, how can I disable one of these? Let's say I want disable `sdch`, how could it be done? I'm not a good programmer so maybe there is an addon for this?

I have downloaded an addon already but it doesn't seem to work.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en downloaded that, added a "request header" and set its value to: `sdch;q=0,deflate;q=0`

However, the `sdch` is still showing up and I don't see any changes...

Is it possible at all? Or maybe I have used a wrong value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no portable way to do this in all browsers. A possible workaround could be to use a local proxy to rewrite the headers, e.g. [privoxy](https://www.privoxy.org/) or [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

**EDIT:**

Just tried [ModHeader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en) and it does seem to work in *Chrome 52*.

Just set `Accept-Encoding` to something like `gzip,deflate`.

Comment: Thank you for answer but I don't want use proxy : /
There is really no way? I don't mind using something else than Chrome browser. Opera / Firefox, I like these too.

Comment: came across this in 2021. Today, in Firefox, use "about:config", then search for "accept-encoding" ....